# Pandas groupby with first is not skipping None values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that contains values that are `None`

When I try to perform a groupby with first it doesn't skip these values and I cannot convert them to nulls before grouping

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1, 29),(1, 50),(2, None),(2, 12),(3,None)]),columns=['day', 'amount'])
df.groupby('day')['amount'].first(dropna=True)
```

I get the error `_cython_agg_general() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna`

Comment: `df.groupby('day')['amount'].first()`?

Comment: `df.groupby('day')['amount'].first()` doesn't work because it doesn't ignore the None value for the 2nd day

Comment: @DanielWyatt then your question doesn't accurately represent your data, or you haven't provided enough version information.  `first` skips that value for me.

Comment: @DanielWyatt what is yours pandas version?

Comment: Yes maybe that's it. Mine is 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1, 29),(1, 50),(2, None), (2, 12)]),columns=['day', 'amount'])
df[~df['amount'].isin([None])].groupby('day', dropna=True)['amount'].first()
```